# Policy and procedure for suicide threats

Tags: united-kingdom, mental-health

I know the companies I have worked for would support their staff during times of depression and bereavement, but is it common practice for companies to have specific policies and procedures for when customers show the same signs?

If it is, where can I find examples. If not, why not?

I work for a pensions company where customers are usually in contact by phone.

Note: no one is at risk

Comment: depends on the industry I would think. An airline I know of specifically trains staff in different situations they might encounter, that is one of them. In my time as a bouncer anyone acting wierdly would be chucked out the door and then left to their own devices.

Comment: It's not "common" practice for "most" companies to deal with suicidal people, regardless if they are employees or customers. Regardless who it is, try convincing the person to get professional help, or even better get someone to come and don't leave the person alone in the meantime. Then let said help handle this (better than any random companies boss etc. could) ... (but I wrote this thinking of some office/shop; being a bouncer surely is different)

Comment: Hm, that's several questions in one: Is it common to have a policy? What is that policy like? Why do not all have one? Please focus your question a bit more. Also, in general questions should be "about an actual problem you have faced". What is that problem?

Comment: And just for the record: If someone threatens suicide, then unless you know them very well, the only appropriate response is to  call an ambulance, which will take them to a psychiatrist immediately (possibly even against their will). Suicide is a serious risk which an outsider cannot judge.

Comment: This feels off-topic to me. We typically deal with practical questions as @sleske mentioned. Purely cerebral questions like "Why is X (not) a thing?" probably aren't valid here unless their answers can contain useful advice. I do think this question can be reworked to fit those criteria.

Comment: Think about the liability on the company side, a customer says something that makes them think they are suicidal, but improper procedures for dealing with this opens up the company to lawsuits about mishandling the situation. As the owner of a company I'd rather have no policy/training at all, unless I were in an industry that deals with those people (mental health/healthcare/law enforcement)...

Comment: By the way, there's a big difference between 'I think this person might commit suicide' and 'This person told me they were going to commit suicide'.

Comment: @DJClayworth and even 'This person is wearing a bulky vest and emitting tick tock sounds'

Answer (score 2):

> If not, why not?

Because the primary focus of a business is parting a customer from his/her money not analysing their mental state. In saying that I would think almost any workplace would try and help someone who was overtly in trouble, customer or not.

Back in my time anyway, today possibly they might just take photo's on their phones.

Except bouncers and suchlike, drunk people can be overly dramatic and threatening to go sideways on life isn't all that uncommon, policy then is that they do it outside.

Tricky situation in an outdoors job, a forestry worker for example might be a whole day travel from professional attention and has easy access to lethal tools, so what protocol could they have? Tie the chap up?

Some industries do give their staff training to handle those sorts of situations. One Airline in particular I know of, but I would assume big hotels and similar would as well. Because they are legally obligated to look after their customers welfare, and because the customer is not usually walk in/walk out, but needs their money milked over a longer period. Plus of course it would be a PR disaster and these industries are all about PR.

So in summary it would depend on the industry to have specific protocols in place, and normal human kindness and empathy in others.

Comment: For hotels specifically, it could cause other problems. I know when you sell a home, you have to disclose if anyone has died in it. It's possible hotels would face the same kind of problem (although if it were me I would simply turn that room into a large storage closet rather than disclose to customers that someone died in it...)

Comment: I know some of the big hotels here have a Doctor on call if not on the premises, I assume they would be called to deal with anything like this. The smaller resorts I guess wouldn't, but someone hanging from the light fixtures would definitely be bad for business.